# Interaction Audioserver and application

Tags: audio, android-emulator

There is a way in order to understand who is interacting with audioserver?For instance if there is an application that uses microphone, is there a way to understand if an interaction between audioserver and application is occurred? And in particular what kind of interaction should be (socket , pipe , shared memory, etc….)?

Comment: As written I can't even tell what part of the OS stack it is directed at. It may help to read: https://source.android.com/devices/audio and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus

Comment: `audioserver` native process hosts one or more framework services. The operating system itself and the apps interact with the services through Binder IPC. AFAIK there's no straightforward way to trace Binder IPC at kernel level. But there's a system service named `binder_calls_stats`. You can dump it and see if it contains your required info. I haven't checked though.